# Finding rows with abnormal status

Tags: python-3.x

| ID | status | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 1 | 2001-01-01 01:00:00 |
| aaa | 1 | 2001-01-01 02:00:00 |
| aaa | 5 | 2001-01-01 03:00:00 |
| aaa | 1 | 2001-01-01 04:00:00 |
| aaa | 6 | 2001-01-01 05:00:00 |
| aaa | 1 | 2001-01-01 06:00:00 |
| aaa | 1 | 2001-01-01 07:00:00 |
| aaa | 4 | 2001-01-01 08:00:00 |
| aaa | 1 | 2001-01-01 09:00:00 |
| aaa | 1 | 2001-01-01 10:00:00 |
| aaa | 1(This should be 2) | 2001-01-01 11:00:00 |

I am meeting a scenario is that need to catch the rows of abnormal status.

the above is demo data.
the data executing every hour, within 10 hours, when the status is 1 and appears 7 times in total, it should change to 2 in the 11th hour. If not, the ID is abnormal status.
My question is how to catch the ID that in abnormal status?
There is a possibility of cross day execution here.
e.g. from 2001-01-11 20:00:00 to 2001-01-12 06:00:00

My language is Python.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.